# What troops are Star Destroyers capable of deploying to a ground assault?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I'm not sure if there are stats on this out there, but I'll take whatever is available.

Most classes of Star Destroyers are designed with providing troops for ground battles among their primary functions. For each class of Star Destroyer, what troops are they capable of contributing to a ground assault under normal circumstances?

Star Destroyer classes that are not designed to be ground-troop carriers (eg. exclusively space-focused Star Destroyers such as the Interdictor-Class) may be excluded from the answer. I'm looking for any available statistic meeting the following context:

- Star Destroyer classes from both Republic and Imperial eras
- Troop composition of the standard, default loadout: Standard infantry, specialised infantry, planetary armaments (ie. walkers, atmospheric fighters, marine armaments etc.)
- Only troops deployed aboard the Star Destroyer at full staffing strength on a permanent basis should count. As an analogy, a certain class of Star Destroyer may have capacity to transport five legions, but only carries two on a permanent basis when at full staffing strength. The remaining capacity allows up to three legions to be temporarily carried onboard to battlefields in particular need of ground troops. Such a Star Destroyer should only be listed in the answer as capable of deploying two legions *under normal circumstances*.

Most of any existing stats should be only in Legends, but I'll accept any canon-version stats as well. Once again, reminder on the first sentence of this post. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm looking through the new canon books "Lost Stars" and "Twilight Company" as those have the most talk of Star Destroyers - nothing substantive so far. Best I can find is a line in Twilight Company that says "capable of carrying armies"

Comment: Is this not mentioned in the cross sections book?

Comment: @Probst Do you have them?

Comment: Not where I can get it, I think I have a copy but it's in storage in my parent's attic lol

Answer (score 3):

The *Acclamator*-class military transport ship carries 16 000 clone troops and support staff (*Complete Cross Sections* p.43). The *Venator*-class ship is a dedicated starfighter carrier and battleship, and carries no troops (but does carry LAAT/i gunships for troop transport and LAAT/c gunships for walker transport). The *Victory*-class Star Destroyer carries 1 600 troops.

*Complete Cross-Sections* (p.107) lists the *Imperial* as carrying 9 700 *stormtroopers*, the [*Imperial Sourcebook*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_Sourcebook_(Second_Edition)) lists 9 700 *troops* but doesn't comment on any split between stormtroopers and Imperial Army troops. The *Imperial Sourcebook* also lists a passenger capacity of 38 000 troops for a *Super*-class Star Destroyer. The Wookieepedia [page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Resurgent-class_Star_Destroyer) on the *Resurgent*-class Star Destroyer lists a capacity of 'over 8 000 stormtroopers'.

Comment: Any idea on how many walkers they carry? I've always been curious about the number of AT-ATs and AT-STs on hand.

Comment: @thegreatjedi An Imperial carries 20 AT-ATs and 30 AT-STs